# Detaching chained commands called with system()

Tags: c, linux, command-line, exec

I'm familiar with executing a shell command from within C using system, like this:

```
system("ifup -a\n");
```

And forking them (so the system() call returns immediately) using ampersand:

```
system("ifup -a &\n");
```

And chaining two commands, one-after-the-other using double-ampersand:

```
system("ifdown eth0 && ifup -a\n");
```

But does it follow that adding a single ampersand on the end of a chain will run the entire chain AND have the system() call return immediately?  For example:

```
system("ifdown eth0 && ifup -a &\n");
```

Does the single ampersand fork the entire line or just the last command?

Or is there a better way to achieve this? We seem to have a fussy networking situation where it is desirable to do this:

```
system("ifdown eth0 && sleep 2 && ifup -a &\n");
```

To give things time to get fully down & fully up again, but the calling function really wants to return immediately.

Comment: Yes it does, and it's very easy to test, which you should have done yourself, instead of asking the question.

Comment: @pelya - I realise I can test it, but it would be nice to find out if it's documented behaviour rather than just "works for me on this particular build", or if there is some more elegant or proper solution, as there frequently is with Linux.

Comment: From 'man system', the system() call is equivalent to fork() and execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0); which should work in a similar way on any Unix-like OS. Not so much on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes adding a single ampersand at the end will make system() return immediately.